# javascript next line(\n) on the string not working

Tags: javascript

Hi this does not make sense I am trying to get put \n to break my sentence but it seems not working ,my code below

```
 "Address:"+location.addressLine1 + " " + location.addressLine2 +"\n "+"Store Name:\n"+ location.storeName +" "+"Geofence:\n"+ location.maxGeofence+" "+"City:\n"+location.city
```

my goal is to have all the rows in new line ,Like below

```
Address:xxxxxxx

Store Name:xxxxxx

Gofence:xxxxxx

City:xxxxxxx
```

but I keep on getting

```
 Address:xxxxxxx Store Name:xxxxxx Gofence:xxxxxx  City:xxxxxxx
```

Comment: If you are displaying as HTML, you need to use `<br/>`

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML/JS where you are displaying this.

Comment: please specify your problem better, both (Address:xxxxx...) look the same and it's hard to tell what's the issue

Comment: @SubirKumarSao <br /> i 've tried it it is not working also

Comment: All info is displayed on the infowindow when you click on the marker on google maps @ArekFlinik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `<br/>` in HTML or, if you wish to keep using `\n`, use the `nl2br` function from **php.js** :

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```

This will convert every `\n` to a `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `\n`, use `<br/>`

`<br />` is [HTML element for a line break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br). `<br />` allows to show up as a *new line* when `HTML` is rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

In html \n has no effect. Replace it with [`<br/>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) or place your code inside `<pre>` tags.

1. `br` - will make a new line inside HTML
2. `pre` - code inside will be formated as it was inside a text file (it will understood \n), but you will have to style it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for newline

```
"Address:"+location.addressLine1 + " " + location.addressLine2 +"<br>"+"Store Name:<br>"+ location.storeName +" "+"Geofence:<br>"+ location.maxGeofence+" "+"City:<br>"+location.city
```

Note : \n is work only php not in Html so \n will not work here.